# add class to element in template event

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This Meteor template code tries to add class to the element without unnecessary calls. `event.currentTarget.addClass('active');` failed to add the class? What am I doing wrong?

```js
// inside the template events
'click #login-form-link': function (event) {
    $('#login-form-link').addClass('active'); // extra call
    event.currentTarget.addClass('active');   // cheap but did not work
 },
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: event.currentTarget.addClass is not a function is the error on the browser console.

Comment: It's a jQuery method, so it's `$(event.currentTarget).addClass('active');` or `event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');`

Comment: That's because the event.currentTarget object isn't a jquery object, so you can't call `addClass()` on it. You will need to use a selector to find it before you can do that

Comment: `$(this).addClass('active')` also failed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the event target into a jQuery object

```
'click #login-form-link'(event) => {
    $(event.target).addClass('active');
 },
```

Note that `this` will be the *data context* behind the element you clicked on, not a DOM element that you can add a class to.

You can't really get rid of the extra call as you need to get a reference to a DOM node somehow, `$(event.target)` is as good as any.

Answer (score 2):

Though this question is already answered, I can't help but mention that this task could be done without using jQuery:

```js
'click #login-form-link'(event) => {
  event.target.classList.add('active');
},
```

`classList` is a property that supports `add()`, `remove()` and `toggle()` methods, just be vary of browser support: some of browsers don't support multiple arguments of those methods, but all of them (excluding really old ones) have basic support.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).